# How do I change the IR checkbox uncheck to checked in PL/SQL? (Oracle Apex 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to create a button that works checkbox status changed.
[image]
When press that button, the same `CAT_FUR_COLOR_ID` rows checkbox are check.
[image]
I was able to get the `CAT_FUR_COLOR_ID` of checked row.
But I don't know how to change other rows data.
Because `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` gave me only the checked rows.

Thank you for you read it. And give me help.

Comment: Please give more information, maybe with a screenshot to show what is is you have now and what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you Koen!
[link for capture](https://file6-d.kuku.lu/files/20221006-2132_1c8bc6007b43c2fe8664245fa822cc80.png)
In this sample case, when checked first row and click the button, then 4 and 7th rows are checked.

Comment: Please update the question with more info - do not put it in the comment. Please share more details. I'm still not clear what exactly the question is. What is it you're doing, what is the result and what is the expected result ? Please provide enough details to properly reproduce.

Comment: Sorry. Update the question with picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without know *what pl/sql the button executes* and without knowing *the sql that is used to generate the report* or *the actual sample data* I can only guess that:

The report repeats the values for the column "Cat Fur Color Id" and my guess is that this is a report using `APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX` with the id value of "Cat Fur Color Id". So if a value is set for cat fur color 03 it will be shown as checked for every occurence of that row.

So if it is checked for cat fur color 03 then that row is updated and when the report is run again every row for cat fur color 03 shows as checked.

Solution: Make sure that the id used in `APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX` uniquely identifies the rows and make sure to update only that row. With repeating rows of the same data what you want is not possible.

Comment: Thank you.
My data I made for the sample was not good, but you did a great job.